# Deriving the Schwarzschild metric in the weak-field regime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, approximations

I am trying to derive the weak-field Schwarzschild metric, but starting from the same form as Schwarzschild:

$ds^2=-(1+2\Phi(r))dt^2+(1-2\Psi(r))dr^2 +r^2 d\Omega^2$

which has $R=-2\partial_r^2 \Phi(r)$ and $R_{00}=\partial_r^2\Phi(r)$. When I use $T^0_0=\rho$, then I get to the equation

$T^0_0=R^0_0 -\frac{1}{2} \delta^0_0 R = -\partial_r^2\Phi(r)+\partial_r^2 \Phi(r)=0$

i.e. $\rho=0$. Is it impossible to derive taking a non-vacuum solution, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $T_{0}{}^{0} = \rho$

Comment: I have changed it, but I don't think it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schwartzschild spacetime is a vacum solution of Einstein equation, whatever you get won't be Schwarzschild's solution.

Furthermore, with [this tool](http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r-1016097922#?in=load(ctensor)%3B%0A%0A(cframe_flag%3Afalse%2Cgcd%3Aspmod%2Cctrgsimp%3Atrue%2Cratfac%3Atrue)%3B%0A%0Alg%3Adiag_matrix(-(1)%2C(1)%2Cr%5E2%2C(sin(%25theta)*r)%5E2)%3B%0A%0Act_coords%3A%5Bt%2Cr%2C%25theta%2C%25phi%5D%3B%0A%0Adepends(%25nu%2C%5Br%2Ct%5D%2C%25lambda%2C%5Br%2Ct%5D)%3B%0A%0Acmetric(false)%3B%0A%0A%0A%20riemann(false)%3B%0A%0Aricci(false)%3B%0A%0Aeinstein(true)%3B%0A%0AR%3Ascurvature()%3B%0A%0A) you can calculate the Einstein tensor. For the metric you have proposed:

$$
G_{00} = \frac{2(r\partial_r\Psi(r)-2\Psi^2(r)+\Psi(r))}{r^2(2\Psi(r)-1)^2}\propto T_{00}
$$

which is not the $G_{00}$ you got. Probably some mistake during the calculation lead to that.

Comment: To be precise, I meant the weak field solution for a spherical object, e.g. here http://www.physicspages.com/2015/01/11/schwarzschild-metric-equivalent-to-weak-field-solution-for-spherical-object/ In the weak field limit, this should reduce to Schwarzschild

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstood.